# SQL GROUP BY does not keep correct order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that I am running this query on:

```
SELECT datetime, from_email, from_name
FROM emails
WHERE user_seq = '1'
GROUP BY from_email
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

the query executes and returns data however it is not showing the data in the order of `datetime DESC`

When I remove the `GROUP BY`, the data shows in the correct order.

Comment: please show some examples of data and explain along with it

Comment: You sure that your query runs successfully? You have 1 column  in your group by but multiple columns in your select. In a group by query you can only select your group by columns and aggregate or user defined functions that returns exactly one result for that group by column

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Any sensible DBMS will reject your statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ,you want to group the results using from_email.. Try with the below script.. and the script is for SQL server..

```
;WITH cte_1
as( SELECT datetime, from_email, from_name
           , ROW_NUMBER ()OVER(PARTITION BY from_email ORDER BY datetime desc) RNo
     FROM emails
     WHERE user_seq = '1')
SELECT datetime, from_email, from_name
FROM cte_1
WHERE RNO=1
```

Following code seems to work in MySql..

```
SELECT datetime, from_email, from_name
FROM emails e
 JOIN (SELECT from_email,MAX(datetime) MaxDate
       FROM emails
       GROUP BY from_email)t on e.from_email=t.from_email AND e.datetime=t.MaxDate
```

Comment: just tried your second block of code but that is returning more than one row for each `from_email` - i want to group by `from_email` and show the row with the `datetime` closest to NOW

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are using `mysql` as it allows you to exclude fields from the `group by` clause that aren't included in an aggregate, in this case, your `datetime` field.  Considering you want to sort the `datetime` descending, perhaps you really just need to use `max`:

```
SELECT max(datetime), 
       from_email, 
       from_name 
FROM emails 
WHERE user_seq = '1' 
GROUP BY from_email, from_name
ORDER BY 1 desc
```

Comment: thats  looking better but i dont want to group by `from_name`, just `from_email` as otherwise i get two lots of similar data that i dont need

Comment: @charlie -- you can remove it and it will "work", but it will just return an arbitrary value from the `from_name` field.  So if you have multiple `from_name` values associated with a single `from_email` value, you cannot guarantee which is returned if you remove it...

Comment: check my data in this image: https://s17.postimg.org/72p6677r3/Screen_Shot_2016_08_30_at_17_52_35.png - so from this, i would like to retrieve the columns with `from_name` `1 - One` and `Two` but not `One`

Comment: @charlie -- what's your question?  As I said, you can remove it, but which name should it return...

Comment: from the sample data, i want it to return the two rows with `from_name` `1 - One` and `Two`